# Toggle ag-grid GridOptions properties during runtime

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Is there a way in ag-grid to change properties of GridOptions like the treeData flag during the runtime?
Background:  I want to change the way my data is getting displayed during runtime by clicking a button. I tried a very simple way by using `agGridOptions.treeData = !this._agGridOptions.treeData;` which doesnßt work for me. I also tried to refresh the View using `this._agGridOptions.api.refreshView();` afterwards without any success. I also tried to run the changeDetection manually afterwards, but also without success
How to change this flag and updating the table during runtime?

Comment: shortly: its impossible via inbuilt features, but you can reload the page with a needed parameter and handle this parameter inside to get the expected result.
check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51159799/4483102

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repopulate ag-grid with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51154999/repopulate-ag-grid-with-data)