# ag-grid: Redrawing grid after Grid Properties change - Vuejs 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, ag-grid

**Issue:** After grid is rendered, and any of the Grid Property is changed (i.e. floating-filter or pagination), there is no documented way to force grid to redraw. Reloading whole page is not an option.

Comment: On a quick Google I found [this doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-refresh/), maybe it helps you. Again, can you include the code that you use for example to try to change pagination?

Comment: Actually, @TobiasK. not fully right with noticing about 'redraw' possibility. If I've got right the contributor question, he needs to reload grid with changed options and honestly, it's not possible by default, only full grid reloading and only via rerendering, check here for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/51159799/4483102