# Dynamically Setting Properties for ag-Grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am having an issue with dynamically changing properties for ag-Grid.

I have created a plunker to demonstrate the issue (see link below).

I created 4 buttons. Each button updates a single grid property (`sideBar`, `enableFilter`, `enableSorting`, and `suppressMenuHide` specifically).

Each button will call a function for their 'click' event to toggle their respective property to `true` or `false`.

The unexpected behavior I am seeing is that toggling the `sideBar` and `enableFilter` properties properly update the UI to show/hide sidebar and filtering respectively. However toggling `enableSorting` and `suppressMenuHide` do not update the UI.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import "ag-grid-enterprise";

@Component({
selector: "my-app",
template: `<button (click)="toggleSidebar()">toggle sidebar</button>
<button (click)="toggleFilter()">toggle filter</button>
<button (click)="toggleSorting()">toggle sorting</button>
<button (click)="toggleMenuHide()">toggle menu hiding</button>
<ag-grid-angular
  #agGrid
  style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
  id="myGrid"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
  [sideBar]="sideBar"
  [enableFilter]="enableFilter"
  [enableSorting]="enableSorting"
  [suppressMenuHide]="suppressMenuHide"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  ></ag-grid-angular>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
  private gridApi;
  private gridColumnApi;
  private rowData: any[];

  private columnDefs;
  private defaultColDef;
  private sideBar:boolean = false;
  private enableFilter:boolean = true;
  private enableSorting:boolean = true;
  private suppressMenuHide:boolean = false;

  toggleSidebar(){
    this.sideBar = !this.sideBar;
    console.log('sidebar set to', this.sideBar);
  }

  toggleFilter(){
    this.enableFilter = !this.enableFilter;
    console.log('filtering set to', this.enableFilter);
  }

  toggleSorting(){
    this.enableSorting = !this.enableSorting;
    console.log('sorting set to', this.enableSorting);
  }

  toggleMenuHide(){
    this.suppressMenuHide = !this.suppressMenuHide;
    console.log('menu hide set to', this.suppressMenuHide);
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.columnDefs = [
      {
        field: "athlete",
        width: 150,
        filter: "agTextColumnFilter"
      },
      {
        field: "age",
        width: 90
      },
      {
        field: "country",
        width: 120
      },
      {
        field: "year",
        width: 90
      },
      {
        field: "date",
        width: 110
      },
      {
        field: "gold",
        width: 100
      },
      {
        field: "silver",
        width: 100
      },
      {
        field: "bronze",
        width: 100
      },
      {
        field: "total",
        width: 100
      }
    ];
    this.defaultColDef = {
      enableValue: true,
      enableRowGroup: true,
      enablePivot: true
    };
  }

  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    this.http
      .get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/packages/ag-grid-docs/src/olympicWinners.json")
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.rowData = data;
      });
  }
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/DyiMUslXbG1f9ppiIQEb?p=preview

Comment: Just a tought, make the attributes used in the template public instead of private. And can you tell us the version of Ag-Grid you're using ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repopulate ag-grid with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51154999/repopulate-ag-grid-with-data)
`gridOptions` doesn't support live changes.

Comment: not working with ` [enableSorting]="true"` setted too

Comment: the [official example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/) is working, see what is the difference

Comment: Even when using the pluker of the official example, changing EnableSorting seems to have no effect at runtime.

Comment: @JFPicard, Thanks for the replies. The plunker is using v19, and I am using v18 in my application. Both versions seem to have the same issue. I tried using public accessors to no avail.

Comment: @un.spike Thanks! I did read that response earlier, however, after testing in Plunker some of the properties do indeed update the UI, just not all of them.

Comment: @Gaspar, Thanks for the comments! I used the official example's plunker as the basis for my plunker, but still does not seem to work.

Comment: @jptrue could you share the sample?

Comment: @un.spike I started at this link: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-side-bar/#example-booleanConfiguration, and clicked on the plunker button and then made my modifications.

Comment: still can't find where did you can dynamically changed `gridOptions`

Answer (score 4):

I played around with your plunker and got it working when I added this line     `this.gridApi.refreshHeader();` to `toggleMenuHide()` and `toggleSorting()`
You need to do this if you dynamically update any property on the header.

From the docs -

> refreshHeader()   Redraws the header. Useful if a column name changes,
>   or something else that changes how the column header is displayed.

Comment: This is the correct answer, ag-grid gridOptions properties are not reactive mostly, you are going to have to find your way around the API and component methods to change things dynamically