# ag-grid and angular, how to switch grid options dynamically

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I have two different grid configurations (represented as two `gridOption` objects). One is loading local data, where the other one is using an elasticsearch datasource with the infinite row model.

If I wire them in the template `[gridOptions]="localOptions"`, `[gridOptions]="elasticGridOptions"` both work perfectly well.

This is my current component and (schematically) what I want to achieve:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-gridtest',
  styleUrls: ['./gridtest.component.css'],
  template: `
    <ag-grid-angular
      id="grid"
      style="width: 100vw;"
      [style.height] = 'height'
      class="ag-theme-balham ag-grid"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
    <button (click)="switchOptions()"></button>
  `
})
export class GridtestComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(
    private esDs: ElasticDatasource
  ) {}

  height = '0px';
  gridApi: any;
  columnsApi: any;
  gridOptions: {};

  columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'Id', field: 'id'},
    {headerName: 'Title', field: 'title'}
  ];

  elasticGridOptions = {
    rowModelType: 'infinite'
  };

  localOptions = {
    rowData: [
      {id: '1', title: 'foo'},
      {id: '2', title: 'bar'},
      {id: '3', title: 'baz'}
    ]
  };

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  resizeGrid(){
    this.height = `${$(window).innerHeight()-60}px`;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.elasticGridOptions['datasource'] = this.esDs;
  }

  onGridReady(params){
    this.resizeGrid();
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.columnsApi = params.columnApi;
  }

  isElastic = false;
  switchOptions(){
    if(this.isElastic){
      this.gridOptions = this.localOptions;
      this.isElastic = false;
    }else{
      this.gridOptions = this.elasticGridOptions;
      this.isElastic = true;
    }

    //reinitialize / update options or grid??
  }

}
```

I wire `[gridOptions]` to a generic options object and then on a button click I try to switch between the two. The interesting thin is, even if I put `this.gridOptions = this.localOptions;` as a last line into `onGridReady` it also doesn't work. I have the feeling I need to somehow tell the grid to actually reload the options, or to reinitialize itself, but I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Currently, `gridOptions` can't be reloaded dynamically.
Check here:

[Dynamically Setting Properties for ag-Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428455/dynamically-setting-properties-for-ag-grid#comment91818935_52428455)

[Repopulate ag-grid with data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51159799/4483102)

You need to re-render your page.
Anyway, you can handle requirement's on `resolver` part to prepare your `options` and then use it in `component`.

> [Ag-grid update 31](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/upgrading-to-ag-grid-31/#gridoptions)

GridOptions
*Javascript - Mutating gridOptions after the grid has been created will no longer be picked up by the grid. Instead use api.setGridOption (property, newValue) to update grid options.*

Since v31 its possible to update `gridOptions` via new API methods:
[`setGridOption`](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-gridOptions-setGridOption) and [`updateGridOptions`](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-gridOptions-updateGridOptions)

Answer (score 0):

I created pagination (let's say) mock. So basically it's a function that sets page-size property to predefined page size (100 for me), or to max rows size, so all rows will be visible.

This is closest I can get without bending grid API, or refreshing page/component

(You can also hide pagination controls if you wish to to have more UX feedback)

```
  /**
   * this is not real toggle nor ag-grid turning pagination dynamically on/off
   * because ag-grid does not support hot-reload of this grid option
   */
  paginationToggle() {
    this.pagination = !this.pagination;

    if(this.pagination){
      this.gridApi.paginationSetPageSize(Number(this.pageSize));
    }
    else{
      this.gridApi.paginationSetPageSize(Number(this.gridApi.paginationGetRowCount()));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is, to update the object itself (add or remove elements), without overriding it.

For example, in the case above, you can do the following:

```js
setLocalOptions(){
  this.gridOptions.rowData = [
      {id: '1', title: 'foo'},
      {id: '2', title: 'bar'},
      {id: '3', title: 'baz'}
    ]
  //this.gridOptions...
  //If you need to remove unnecessary elements, then remove them here.
}

setElasticGridOptions(){
  //same as above
}

switchOptions(){
  if(this.isElastic){
    this.setLocalOptions();
    this.isElastic = false;
  }else{
    this.setElasticGridOptions();
    this.isElastic = true;
  }
}
```