# Ag grid not refresh pagination status on pagination changing

Tags: ag-grid

Below is a link to the ag-grid example.
The problem is that when a data array (its length) changes, the ag-grid sees a change in the data, but not a value of pagination.
Although this value is correctly transmitted and displayed.
It does not allow to remove pagination when it is not necessary to show it.
Calling api.redrawRows (), as it turned out, also does not solve the problem.
Any ideas?
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/OTthZcnGn5ksRXZw

Comment: You can mock this behavior,
here is my post how i did it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52519129/ag-grid-and-angular-how-to-switch-grid-options-dynamically/70757699#70757699

Answer (score 1):

You wanna achieve dynamic handling of options, but unfortunately `ag-grid` still doesn't support hot-reload for most of `gridOptions`

[Similar post/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52519796/4483102)