# How can I dynamically change the options of ag-Grid?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am creating an ag-grid with the below code. I would like to dynamically change the rowSelection option from single to multiple onClick of a button.

```
<ag-grid-angular 
  #validateGrid
  style="width: 780px; height: 260px;" 
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  rowSelection="single"
  suppressRowClickSelection="false"
  suppressHorizontalScroll="true" 
  [rowData]="rowData" 
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" 
  [getRowNodeId]="getRowNodeId"
  (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged()"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" 
  enableCellTextSelection=true>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

In my Typescript code, I have tried `this.gridOptions.rowSelection = 'multiple';` but this does not work. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ag-grid and angular, how to switch grid options dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52519129/ag-grid-and-angular-how-to-switch-grid-options-dynamically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

your tmpl:

```
<ag-grid-angular 
  #validateGrid
  style="width: 780px; height: 260px;" 
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  rowSelection="{{rowSelection}}" // Updated
  suppressRowClickSelection="false"
  suppressHorizontalScroll="true" 
  [rowData]="rowData" 
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" 
  [getRowNodeId]="getRowNodeId"
  (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged()"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" 
  enableCellTextSelection=true>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

your ts.

```
public rowSelection: string = 'single';

public changeRowSelection(): void {
    this.rowSelection = 'multiple'; // this is example
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this doesn't seem to be working for me.